# RegEx for names in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of names:

```
Jacqueline Beaurivage   (loh Da road); 
Bon Van Daht (fary goal lim)
Bon Jobi (ting wei)
Ting Wan (dehtee road);
```

How can I use the C# string search methods to store the names into a variable?

Basically I don't want anything after " (" and onwards. What would be the most efficient and simple way?

Answer (score 9):

```
var name = string.Split('(')[0].Trim()
```

Comment: +1. Using explicit code instead of RegEx often gives much easier to read and debug solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Regex("^[^(]+", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(string);
```

Comment: +0: This maybe what OP wants, but without explanation it is not very usable (unlike `Split` option).